# onChange и onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я делаю поиск по сайту, но столкнулся с проблемой, когда я вешаю input 2 события onChange и onKeyPress, то onChange просто отказывается работать.

```
    const onKeyPress = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (event.key === 'Enter') search();

    };

    const onChange = event => {
        setValue({
            search: event.target.value
        })
    };

return(
<form className="form-inline pull-xs-right">
   <input style={{height:"35px", borderRadius: "5px"}} value={value.search} onChange={onChange} onKeyPress={onKeyPress} placeholder="Поиск"/>
</form>)
```

Comment: а если убрать с события onKeyPress строку e.preventDefault()?

Comment: Заработало, даже не думал, что в этом мб быть проблема

Comment: отметьте как решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а если убрать с события onKeyPress строку e.preventDefault()?